# How to safely replace values in data.frame even when data.frame is empty?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm having trouble writing safe code to manipulate data frames in R. The problem I'm having is that `df[...] <- (...)` is vulnerable to the data.frame having no rows (among other things!).

Example 1:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = c(NA, 5))
df[is.na(df$b), 'b'] <- 0
```

Does what I want - replaces NA with 0.

Example 2:

```
df.empty <- data.frame(a = character(), b = character())
df.empty[is.na(df.empty$b), 'b'] <- 0
df.empty[is.na(df.empty$b), 'b', drop = F] <- 0
```

Both attempts to mutate the data frame in Example 2 result in an error (either replacement has 1 row, data has 0; or 'unused argument (drop = F)).

I find that very annoying.

How do I **universally** mutate a column based on arbitrary (vector) criterion in a data.frame, without having to manually check for all possible conditions like NA, NULL, no rows, coercion to vector because of no rows, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using `dplyr`?

This example, combining `mutate()` and `ifelse()`, seems to achieve what you want.

```
df.empty <- df.empty %>% 
    mutate(b = ifelse(is.na(b), 0, b))
```

Comment: Are you calling `dplyr` for the hype of it? You could just do `transform(df.empty, b = ifelse(is.na(b), 0, b))` with base R

Comment: @DavidArenburg yeah, maybe for the hype of it!, ..., the thing is that when I wanted something like what @JakubP. is asking, it was in the middle of a dplyr chain (e.g. after joining tables, to replace na for 0, but eventually the join can be empty). So, I automatically thought `dplyr` when I read the question. Do you see this as a problem?, ..., I just like it. Maybe you don't, perhaps you prefer everything in base R or `tsql`?

Comment: Yeah I like everything in base R and `tsql` (as my tags suggest)

Comment: Yeah, dplyr solution is fine, however, that means adding dplyr to almost all code I write for the sake of this trivial need. (dplyr seems to have huge requirements in terms of building from source at first glance - ~200 MB!)

@DavidArenburg, thanks for `transform()`, seems to do the job.

Comment: So you basically accepted the solution that you aren't going to use. Interesting

Comment: @DavidArenburg When an answer and a comment to that answer give me what I need, I accept them. You wouldn't?

Comment: I used this: `empty.df %>% {transform(., row.id = {if(nrow(.)==0) integer(0) else 1:nrow(.)} )}` having the advantage of not requiring `b` to exist. I did try to use `ifelse` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I see a logical problem with the vector criterion in your second example.  In the following code:

```
df.empty <- data.frame(a = character(), b = character())
df.empty[is.na(df.empty$b), 'b'] <- 0
```

You are using the criterion `is.na` to select a range of rows, but there are no rows, so it returns `factor(0)`, which is not a valid range.  Consider this example:

```
df.empty <- data.frame(a = numeric(), b = numeric())
df.empty[1:2, 'b'] <- 0

> df.empty
   a b
1 NA 0
2 NA 0
```

When you use a valid range as your criterion, there is no problem making the assignment.  I chose to use `numeric` columns for simplicity.

Comment: `is.na(df.empty$b)` is a logical vector - `logical(0)` - so it's a valid data frame selection.

Comment: `logical(0)` is a special case.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by special case :) I can get numeric indexes by `which(is.na(df.empty$b))`, however, I still get the error of assigning a vector to an empty data.frame :(

Comment: How many rows would you like to create with `df.empty[logical(0), 'b'] <- 0`, keeping in mind `logical(0)` is the empty set?

Comment: I don't want to create rows. I also don't want to do df.empty[logical(0), ...]. What I'm looking for is a consistent, simple way to use [] operator or similar standard grammar to replace values in data.frame with a given condition. dplyr (another answer) might be an answer to that, but I find it hard to believe base R doesn't support this.

Answer (score 0):

If each element of the empty set is mapped to 0, we still have the empty set.
So in example 2 the data frame should not be affected by the assignment.
I don't know why, but to get rid of the error message it helps to make a data table:

```
df.empty <- data.frame(a = character(), b = character())
setDT(df.empty)
df.empty[is.na(df.empty$b), 'b'] <- 0
df.empty
```

No error message:

```
> source('~/.active-rstudio-document', echo=TRUE)

> df.empty <- data.frame(a = character(), b = character())

> setDT(df.empty)

> df.empty[is.na(df.empty$b), 'b'] <- 0

> df.empty
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: a,b
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rep()` a lot.

I do things like this:

```
df.empty[is.na(df.empty$b), 'b'] <- rep(0, sum(is.na(df.empty$b)))
```

In this way you generate an n-length vector of 0's, where n is the number of rows to replace and may also be 0.

In this case it's a bit kludgy, but I often use it as `df[,"col"] <- rep(x, nrow(df))`.